# How can I do the equivalent of git rebase -i HEAD~2 in eGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I know how to rebase onto a specific branch or tag using eGit in Eclipse, but I haven't found a way to rebase onto a specific sha1 using eGit. I'd like to do this in order to squash commits before pushing to upstream (ie, doing `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where n is some number of commits ago where I want to rebase). Is this possible with eGit? If not, is there another Eclipse plugin I should be using that would provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently available in `Eclipse Oxygen`, it has it's own wizard for it.

1. Get the branch you want in the `History` view
2. Right-click the commit **before** the one you want to change
3. Find `Rebase interactive` and click it
4. The Rebase wizard will show up with the commits available to work upon

It works just like the console version, but on a GUI. Even if conflicts arise, it will help you through.

Answer (score 8):

EGit has rebase, but it does not yet have the interactive rebase you ask for.

Comment: see the following links for progress on this feature:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340967
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356939

Comment: This feature will be available in Eclipse Luna and can already be installed. See http://m-sohn.blogspot.com/2013/11/interactive-rebase-with-egit-32.html

Comment: It is currently available in `Oxygen`.

Answer (score 8):

I've been successful squashing commits using steps from [this post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/441231/989663/#msg_989663) (cut and pasted here):

If I want to squash the last m commits on the current branch then I

- select in history the first commit which I don't want to squash
- right-click and say "Team->Reset->Soft"
- right-click and say "Commit". This commit will contain all the changes of the last m commits together

Answer (score 0):

From the history view select the commit you want to rebase to, and create a branch called `rebase-point` or whatever.  Voila, you can now rebase to that branch, and delete it later if you want.  I generally prefer using a named branch for things like this anyway, because it minimizes the chance for mistakes on my part.  Alternately, consider that `origin/master` is often the right rebase point if you're squashing commits for a push.

Comment: Like when trying to rebase on top of a specific commit via @KevinSawicki's answer, I also get the "Rebase did nothing, HEAD was already up to date" message when I try this? I think I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't know what...

Comment: Hmm, looks like you'll have to do it in the feature branch before merging it into `master`, due to eclipse "helping" you too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rebase from the Eclipse History view.

- Select the repository from the Git Repositories view
- Right-click and select *Show In History*
- Select the commit you want to rebase the currently checked out branch on top of
- Right-click and select the *Rebase on Top of* item
- Note: You may need to select *Show All Branches and Tags* first from the History view toolbar to display the commit you are looking for in the table.

Comment: I should have added this info to the question, but this is how I initially thought it would work, too. However doing this on a previous commit in the same branch always just pops up a dialog saying "Rebase did nothing, HEAD was already up to date."